# Implicit random variable value

Tags: probability, random-variable

Wikipedia freely uses notation $P(Y|X)$, to usually mean $P(Y=y|X=x)$. Is there any other use of this notation (random variable within a PMF without mention of a particular value)? In other words, can I (mentally) insert the =value any time I see this sort of thing? Additionally, is this notation well accepted?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that the things are exactly as you have described. In [some cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) people mean random events $A$ and $B$, not random variables, and there is no need to put something like $=...$. And when they mean random variables, I think it is very usuall to replace the strict notation $P(Y=y|X=x)$ with a frivolous $P(Y|X)$, if it does not lead to confusion. Personally I have never seen situations, when writing $P(Y|X)$ somebody assumed a random variable $P$, which is a function of $X$ and $Y$...